# openwrap offline or local only mode

Tags: openwrap

I want to build a wrap for some shared code and publish it locally to my system repo, then I want to go to another project that depends on it and update the wrap for that project to test my changes.

Is there a way to run `o update-wrap` so it will only update project wraps using newer versions found in the system repo?

I want to avoid needless round trips to remote servers every time I update a locally built wrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an interesting feature to have indeed. There's a feature for this at https://github.com/openrasta/openwrap/issues/204 that hasn't been built yet, which would let you do

```
o update-wrap -fromX system
```

This would only use the system repository to update packages. Would that solve this for you? It's very trivial to implement and could be in the next release.